# Uploading a csv to an api in R

Tags: r, api, csv

To make calls to the census geocoder api I am using tips from the documentation found at http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/Geocoding_Services_API.pdf under the heading "Batch Geocoding". The shell command they give for calling the api for a batch is

```
curl --form addressFile=@address.csv --form benchmark=4 http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch --output geocoderesult.csv
```

where address.csv is the file to be uploaded.

This works perfectly. However, I would like to create an R script to make the whole process automated.

What would be an equivalent way to do the above command in R? Could postForm() in the RCurl package accomplish this?

---

BTW, each line of the csv file getting uploaded ("address.csv") must be of the form

```
Unique ID, Street address, City, State, ZIP
```

So, for example, it could just contain addresses for Apple and Facebook like

```
1, 1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA, 95014
2, 1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, CA, 94025
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `httr` library, a direct translation would be

```
library('httr')

apiurl <- "http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch"

addresses <- "1, 1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA, 95014
2, 1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, CA, 94025"

addresseFile <- "addresses.csv"
writeLines(addresses , addresseFile )

resp<-POST(apiurl, body=list(addressFile=upload_file(addresseFile), benchmark=4), 
     encode="multipart")
content(resp)
```

If you wanted to skip writing the csv file to disk, you could do

```
resp <- POST(apiurl, body=list(
    addressFile = RCurl::fileUpload(
      filename = "data.csv", 
      contents = addresses, 
      contentType = "application/octet-stream"
    ), 
    benchmark=4
  ), 
  encode="multipart"
)
```